# Writing to a QListWidget from OpenCV window

Tags: qt, opencv, qlistwidget

I am writing an application for manually selecting regions of interest from an image. Two windows will appear:

1. An OpenCV window, where the user should select a ROI with the mouse.
2. A QT window, where the selected ROI's coordinates will appear (in a QListWidget)

My problem is how to write onto the QListWidget of the QT window from the OpenCV mouse listener. I guess I have to write a function inside my QT class that returns a pointer to the QListWidget, but I havent managed to do it.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is my main:

```
#include "myclass.h" 
#include <QApplication>
#include </PathToOPENCV/opencv/cv.h>
#include </PathToOPENCV/opencv/highgui.h>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QListWidget>

using namespace cv;

// Pointer to list widget? Should I use it as a global variable to recieve the pointer of the QListWidget?

QListWidget * ptrToList;

void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){

    if( evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP){
        // WRITE HERE ONTO QListWidget!
        // Something like:
        ptrToList->addItem("blah");
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /*----- OPENCV STUFF ----*/

    String windowName = "selectionWindow";
    namedWindow( windowName , CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Mat theImage = imread("/PATHTOIMAGE/1.jpg");
    imshow( windowName,theImage );

    /* ---- Mouse Listener setup ----- */

    setMouseCallback( windowName, mouseEvent , 0 );

    /* ---- QT Stuff ---- */

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    myClass w;
    w.show();

    // Should I do something like this?
    ptrToList = w->getListPtr("listWidget");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is myclass.h

```
namespace Ui {
class myClass;
}

class myClass : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myClass();

private:
    Ui::myClass *ui;

    QListWidget * getListPtr(QString listName){
        QListWidget * theList;
        // None of these work...
        //theList = this->parent()->getChild( listName );
        //theList = this->getChild( listName );
        return(theList);
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

@Roku,

I tried your suggestion, but I think I did it wrong. I added a function in myclass for setting up the mouse callback, so myclass.h is like this:

```
#include <functions.cpp>
using namespace cv;

namespace Ui {
class myClass; /* error: forward declaration of 'struct Ui::myClass' */
}

class myClass : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myClass();

    void setInnerMouseCallback(String windowName){ 
        setMouseCallback( windowName, mouseEvent , ui->listWidget ); /* error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::myClass'*/
    }

private:
    Ui::myClass *ui;
}
```

Then, I added a functions.cpp file with the following code:

```
void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
    QListWidget * theList = (QListWidget*) param;
    if( evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP){

        theList->addItem("blah");
    }
}
```

Is this correct? I get a couple of errors where pointed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Move the actual implementation of setInnerMouseCallback function to myclass.cpp. In the myclass.h Ui::myClass is only forward declared and the compiler doesn't know that it contains stuff like listWidget.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the `setMouseCallback()` is called as "user data" and its type is `void*`. It is designed to be used for just this kind of information. You could to move the `setMouseCallback()` function call to your main window. And then you could use the function like this:

```
setMouseCallback(windowName, mouseEvent, ui->listWidget);
```

In the mouse event callback function you would have a pointer to the list widget:

```
void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    if( evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        QListWidget* listWidget = (QListWidget*)param;
        listWidget->addItem("blah");
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get a couple of errors when I tried your suggestion. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How could I know? What errors are you getting? I would suggest moving that OpenCV stuff from main() to main window if possible.